# Bulkify Trigger

Tags: trigger, bulkification

**Updated**

Any better way without looping circuits__c records and checking all conditions again after getting Building__c map

```
    trigger UpdateLoc on Circuits__c (before insert, before Update) {
    
    list<Id> bldgIdList = new list<Id>();
        
    for(Circuits__c ckt:trigger.new){
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
             if((ckt.Loc__c == NULL) && (ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'ARDU' || ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'LADA') && (ckt.Building__c != null)){
               bldgIdList.add(ckt.Building__c);
             }
         }
        
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
          if(((ckt.Loc__c == NULL) && (ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'ARDU' || ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'LADA') && (ckt.Circuit_Type__c != trigger.oldmap.get(ckt.id).Circuit_Type__c) && (ckt.Building__c != null)) || ((ckt.Building__c != null) && (ckt.Building__c != trigger.oldmap.get(ckt.id).Building__c)  && (ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'ARDU' || ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'LADA'))){
             bldgIdList.add(ckt.Building__c);
           }
         }
        
      }
    
    map<Id,Building__c> bldgMap = new map<Id,Building__c>([select id,CO__c, POP__c from Building__c where id in: bldgIdList]);
    
    for(Circuits__c ckt:trigger.new){
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
             if((ckt.Loc__c == NULL) && (ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'ARDU' || ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'LADA') && (ckt.Building__c != null) ){
                 Building__c b = bldgMap.get(ckt.Building__c);
                 String coPop;
                if(ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'LADA'){
                    if( b.CO__c == Null){
                        CoPop = b.POP__c;
                        if(coPOP == 'Midtown'){
                            coPOP = 'MTN';
                        }else if(coPOP == 'DownTown'){
                            coPOP = 'DTN';
                        }else if(coPOP == 'UpTown'){
                            coPOP = 'UPTN';
                        }else{coPOP = null;}                   
                    }
                }
                else
                 {
                  coPop =b.CO__c; 
                 }
                
                ckt.Loc__c = coPop;
                 
             }
         }
        
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
          if(((ckt.Loc_A__c == NULL) && (ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'ARDU' || ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'LADA') && (ckt.Circuit_Type__c != trigger.oldmap.get(ckt.id).Circuit_Type__c) && (ckt.Building__c != null)) || ((ckt.Building__c != null) && (ckt.Building__c != trigger.oldmap.get(ckt.id).Building__c)  && (ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'ARDU' || ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'LADA') && (ckt.Loc__c == NULL))){
                Building__c b = bldgMap.get(ckt.Building__c);
                String coPop;
                if(ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'LADA'){
                    if(b.Allied_CO__c == Null){
                        CoPop = b.POP__c;
                        if(coPOP == 'Midtown'){
                            coPOP = 'MTN';
                        }else if(coPOP == 'DownTown'){
                            coPOP = 'DTN';
                        }else if(coPOP == 'UpTOWN'){
                            coPOP = 'UPTN';
                        }else{coPOP = null;}                   
                    }
                }
                else{
                     coPop = b.CO__c; 
                  }
                
                ckt.Loc__c = coPop;
            }
         }
        
      }
    
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? This seems fairly easy, you just need to move your SOQL out of the for loop and query for all the Building__c records you need instead of one, put the results in a map and use that in your loop.

Comment: @AlexTennant But I need to check the condition again in for loop as inBeforeInsert I will not have Ids of Circuits__c.Is there any better way to write above trigger without checking conditions again ?

Comment: @AlexTennant Is there any better way without looping through all circuits again after we add Building records to map ?

Comment: @AlexTennant Updated my trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I made some changes to bulkify it expecting this may solve your problem.

```
trigger UpdateLoc on Circuits__c (before insert, before Update) {

        List<Building__c> Bldg = new List<Building__c>();
        Map<Id, Building__c> buildMap=new Map<Id, Building__c>();
                buildMap = [select id, CO__c,POP__c from Building__c limit 50000];

        for(Circuits__c ckt:trigger.new){
            Building__c bil = new Building__c();
            bil = buildMap.get(ckt.Building__c);
            if((ckt.Loc__c ==NULL) && 
                ( ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'ARDU' || ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'LADA') 
                && (ckt.Building__c != null)){


                String coPop;
                if((ckt.Circuit_Type__c == 'LADA') && (Bil.CO__c == Null)){

                        CoPop = Bil.POP__c;
                        if(coPOP == 'Midtown'){
                            coPOP = 'MTN';
                        }else if(coPOP == 'DownTown'){
                            coPOP = 'DTN';
                        }else if(coPOP == 'Uptown'){
                            coPOP = 'UTN';
                        }else{coPOP = null;}                   

                }
                else
                    {
                     coPop = CO__c; 
                   }

                ckt.Loc__c = coPop;
            } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: You are putting all Building Records into map.

Comment: ya I am aware about that, expecting there might be less records or he can modify as per his isssue by itterating the trigger.new .